# How do I evaluate $\sum_{r=1}^{n} [r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)] $?

Tags: summation

I need to evaluate:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{r=1}^{n} [r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)]
\end{equation}

But I don't know where to start. Can someone possibly give a hint?

I need to solve this using telescopic series.

Comment: Compute answers for small $n$. Then try to guess the general answer. Then try to prove it.

Comment: You could also expand it in terms of $r^4$, $r^3$, $r^2$, $r$ and $r^0$ and then use the formulas for those sums separately.

Comment: @Slugger: Can I do it without using the sum formula for $r^4$

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Do you know how to telescope $r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$ and $r(r+1)(r+2)$?

Comment: @HatMan Sorry, a typo, the question was: $r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$ instead of $r(r+1)(r+2)(r+2)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3) = \frac15\left((r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)(r+5)- r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)(r+4)\right) \\
$$

Comment: Sorry I had a typo, can you please see the updated question?

Comment: thx, have adjusted the suggestion

Comment: Okay, got it thank you..

Answer (score 9):

$r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3) = 24\binom{r+3}{4}$, and since
$$ \sum_{k=j}^{N}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{N+1}{j+1}$$
holds by induction, we have:
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{n} r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3) = 24\sum_{r=1}^{n}\binom{r+3}{4} = 24\binom{n+4}{5} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}{5}.$$

Comment: ... and this formula may be how David found his mysterious answer.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest expanding the product to get $$\sum_{r=1}^n(r^4+6r^3+11r^2+6r) = \\ =\sum_{r=1}^n r^4 + 6\sum_{r=1}^n r^3 + 11\sum_{r=1}^n r^2 + 6\sum_{r=1}^n r$$
Now the problem is finding formulas for these sums. The linear sum you probably know (or should) and you might know the sum of squares too. For the ones you don't, it's useful to know that the sum $\sum_{r=1}^n r^k$ is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $k+1$. Therefore if you calculate the first $k+1$ sums, you'll get a linear system of equations in the coefficients (to be determined) of the polynomial.

For example, take $S(n) = \sum_{r=1}^nr^2$. We conjecture that this is equal to $an^3+bn^2 + cn + d$. First of all note that $d = 0$, necessarily. Next: $$\begin{align}S(1) &= 1 &= & a + b + c \\ S(2) &= 5 &= & 8a + 4b + 2c \\ S(3) &= 14 &= &27a + 9b + 3c\end{align}$$
Use your preferred method to solve the system. The same will go for the other sums.

This is quite a brute force method and as such it'll be tedious, but it's good to have in your arsenal of strategies. Additionally, you can skip the intermediate step of calculating the first $n$ squares, cubes, etc. by conjecturing from the very beginning that the sum is a polynomial of degree 5.

**Edit**: I now see you need to use the telescoping sum, so disregard if you wish. I will leave the answer anyway for any who might find it useful.

Comment: Thanks for answering :D Atleast i got do know how to derive sum formulas. I already marked it +10

Comment: @Nivedita Glad I could help.